# Aggregation. Using $let inside $match

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have read about using `$let` in mongo aggregation. But all the examples use `$let` only inside `$project` stage. I wonder if it is possible to use `$let` inside `$match` stage of aggregation? Here is a simple example:

```
var Color = "Black";

db.mydata.aggregate([
    { "$match": {     
       "Category": "MyCategory",
       "Location":"London",
       "Color": $let: {
                  vars: {
                    "Color": Color
                  },
                  in: { 
                    "$$Color" 
                  }
                }
}},    
    // other stages as group, project and sort
    ...
])
```

The above complains about `Expected expression...` So is it possible in some way to use `$let` inside `$match` or other stages of aggregate?

`EDIT:`
That does not work as well:

```
var Color = "Black";

db.mydata.aggregate([
    { "$match": {     
       "Category": "MyCategory",
       "Location":"London",
       "Color": "$$Color"
}},    
    // other stages as group, project and sort
    ...
])
```

But according to https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/aggregation-variables/ it should?
Best Regards

Comment: what's the purpose?

Comment: @hyades To create aggregate query dynamically with user defined variables outside of aggregate.

Comment: That can be done like here it can be `"Color": Color` What's the exact purpose?

Comment: @hyades Sorry dont quite understand what you mean. I mean that if I have a user who clicks in color in input-box in website, the user can then change color to another color and the new aggregate query will be made to mongo. So Color variable needs to be dynamic in aggregate, not static.

Comment: @hyades Please see edit as well.

Comment: If you were doing this in node, it would pick the value of the `Color` variable anyways and replace it with the string `Black` when executing the query. 
There's no need to "$$Color", just it normally like you did in the `vars` object you did initially.

Comment: @hyades Aaaah haha, true... Works just like charm to use `"Color": Color` in `$match`. Post as answer and I accept. Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just straight away use the variables.Node or mongo shell will take care of replacing the variables against strings. No need to store them as internal mongo variables or aggregation variables.

```
var Color = "Black";

db.mydata.aggregate([
    { "$match": {     
       "Category": "MyCategory",
       "Location":"London",
       "Color": Color // this would be replaced by string "Black" by node
}},    
    // other stages as group, project and sort
    ...
])
```

This query executes in Mongo as

```
db.mydata.aggregate([
        { "$match": {     
           "Category": "MyCategory",
           "Location":"London",
           "Color": "Black" 
    }},    
        // other stages as group, project and sort
        ...
    ])
```